# How to send Message to all registered users with android gcm?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am using android gcm to make push notifications for my users. Everything is working so fine. To send a notification I need the users registration id to identify him. It works. Now my problem is that I have some hundreds of users and I would like to inform them ALL about certain updates.

Is there a way to send a notification to all users?
Do I really have to push them all by their registration ids?

On the server side I am using PHP and CURL as it is shown in many examples around here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to broadcast to all users with a single post.

You need to send every ID in blocks of up to 1000 ID's. So if you have 2500 ID's, you need to split that up into 3 posts. 1-1000, 1001-2000, 2001-2500.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the new GCM topics you could create a "all users" topic, and have the app subscribe to that topic when it starts up.  Then a single topic post could go to all the users (I think the limit is a million but you probably should check that).

Comment: Yes, but you have to subscribe to the topic from the client device. If you already have the tokens but they are not subscribed to a topic you can't do anything, except update the app and subscribe the user to a topic or just send the requests in batches using the current tokens you have.

Comment: Also note that there is a limit of one million users subscribed to your apps topic.